# Airflow Xcom with SSHOperator

Tags: ssh, airflow

Im trying to get param from SSHOperator into Xcom and get it in python.

```
def decision_function(**context):
     ti = context['ti']
     output_ssh= ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='ssh_task')
     print('ssh output is: {}'.format(output_ssh))

ls = SSHOperator(
    task_id="ssh_task",
    command=  "ls",
    ssh_hook = sshHook,
    dag = mydag)


get_xcom = PythonOperator(
     task_id='test',
     python_callable=decision_function,
     provide_context=True,
     dag=mydag

ls >> get_xcom
```

I get the wrong result in the xcom_pull:

> ssh output is: MTcySyBhaXJmbG93CTIuMUcgQXV0b0hpdHVtX05ld

Every thing is work fine with BashOperator but when I try to use the SSH, it not working currect.
I also try to change in the config the enable_xcom_pickling param, but still not working.

airflow: 2.1.4
linux

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The value of Xcom may be b64encoded depending on the value of `enable_xcom_pickling` as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/ab762a5a8ae147ae33500ee3c7e7a73d25d03ad7/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.py#L176-L179)
The issue you are facing has been discussed in [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/20473) which suggested to change functionality to be like other operators but the PR was not merged and you can see the reasons for it in the code review comments.

if you wish you can create custom version of the operator without the `enable_xcom_pickling` condition:

```
class MySSHOperator(SSHOperator):

    def execute(self, context=None) -> Union[bytes, str]:
        result: Union[bytes, str]
        if self.command is None:
            raise AirflowException("SSH operator error: SSH command not specified. Aborting.")

        # Forcing get_pty to True if the command begins with "sudo".
        self.get_pty = self.command.startswith('sudo') or self.get_pty

        try:
            with self.get_ssh_client() as ssh_client:
                result = self.run_ssh_client_command(ssh_client, self.command)
        except Exception as e:
            raise AirflowException(f"SSH operator error: {str(e)}")
        return result.decode('utf-8')
```